# Latest modification of text files (in a path)

Tags: bash, scripts, gnu-screen

I am not an expert in this whole scripting stuff but I really need help creating the following bash file:

1. The bash script should open a screen:

   ```
   screen -d -m /home/cs2d/cs2d_dedicated &
   ```
2. The script should now just wait 20 seconds before it starts the third step.
3. After that, it should look periodically in the path `/home/cs2d/sys/logs/` for any kind of modifications of text files within 60 seconds.

   If there are any kind of text file modifications in that path within 60 seconds, it should just repeat the third step *(that just means to look again for modifications within 60 seconds)*.

   If there are not any kind of text file modifications in that path within 60 seconds, it should kill the opened screen of step one and start itself again *(that means to begin again with step 1)*.

**That's it!**

I would appreciate it if anyone can write this bash script for me.

Comment: Read `man find`, especially the section about `-mtime`, I think

Comment: Alternatively you could  probably also monitor the directory with `inotifywait` and its timeout option.

Comment: Are other languages aside from Bash fine, e. g. Python or Perl? Are other terminal multiplexers (e. g. `tmux`) fine or does it have to be `screen`? Should the program wait between individual iterations of step 3? How long?

Comment: It can be used any language that works on my vServer (Ubuntu 14.04 64 Bit) and other terminal multiplexers are also allowed. That means >tmux is allowed. What do you mean exactly with individual iterations of step 3? Well, if the script finds modifications within 60 seconds it should wait until the 60 seconds are over and look for modifications, again. If it doesn't find modifications within 60 seconds the entire script should be canceled to start it again.